# Filter list Div's via checkboxex via DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

based my previous question asked here:
[Jquery Filter List DIVs via checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180129/jquery-filter-list-divs-via-checkboxes)
i got in the situation when both checkboxes and the list is generated from javascript so if i look in view source i could't see them .
I manage to find out that i could access the checkboxes via:

```
$(".bedroomType").attr("type", "input").change(function(){}
```

but i can't make the list to filter...
How should be changed in this case this code?

```
 $(".bedroomType").attr("type", "input").change(function(){
   $(".bedroomType").attr("type", "input").each(function(){

        var checked = $(this).attr('checked') || false;
        var numberofrooms = $(this).data('bedrooms');
        alert(numberofrooms);
        $('.listing').each(function(){
            if ($(this).data('bedrooms')==numberofrooms){
                checked ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

thank you

Comment: Can you post some sample HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code won't work because you cannot give the filter authority to both `show()` AND `hide()` items in the listing. In general, a filter should either `show()` OR `hide()` (or similar), and in this case it should `hide()`.

You will find it more convenient to organise the code into a 'master' filter that calls the 'bedroom' filter and (eventually) other filters. The master should ensure that all listing items are initially shown, so that the filters can selectively hide them.

It is tempting to think that you could alternatively do things the other way round - namely to `hide()` all items initially, then allow the filters to selectively `show()`. But this would not work because no individual filter should have the authority to `show()` - other filters may have a different opinion! With a filter-set of this type, you want items to show only if they meet ALL criteria, not ANY one.

Here's some code:

```
function filterListingByBedrooms($listing){
    var selectedBeds = [];
    $(".bedroomType").each(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            selectedBeds.push($(this).data('bedrooms'));//build array of checked bedroom numbers
        }
    });
    $listing.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if(!$.inArray($this.data('bedrooms'), selectedBeds)) {
            $this.hide();
        }
    });
}

function filterListingByType($listing){
    ...;
}

function filterListingByLocation($listing){
    ...;
}

function filterListing(){
    var $listing = $('.listing').show();//Initially show all, then allow filters to selectively hide.
    filterListingByBedrooms($listing);
    filterListingByType($listing);//apply other filter
    filterListingByLocation($listing);//apply other filter
};

$(".bedroomType").change(filterListing);
$(".propertyType").change(filterListing);
$(".location").change(filterListing);
```

Comment: thank you very much seems exactly what i need just i really tried and i couldn't make this work .. could you please add this working in http://jsfiddle please?Thank you again

Comment: @Teodor; could you check the jsfiddle link please?